# Deployment slots on Web App to different resource groups

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I am having different slots for a web app on azure for dev, test, production. I need to move different slots to their respective resource groups.

Can different slots for a single web app be in different resource groups? I tried to move a slot to different resource but gives me error  (The list of resources in move definition cannot be null or empty. (Code: InvalidResourceMoveRequest)). Cannot make out much from the error. Is there a way to get more details on this error somewhere?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> Can different slots for a single web app be in different resource groups?

You **could not move the slot to other resource group**, because the azure slot is **not a top level resource**.
This means that you could move the top level resource in order to move the child resource.

You could get more details about the [limitation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-move-resources#app-service-limitations) when moving resources to new group or subscription.

Comment: Late answer but this confuses me since Microsoft suggests this pattern in their namning convention for resource groups: <service short name>-<environment>-rg. How can i name my resource group with enviroment like "dev" or "prod" if i have different slots in that resource group for that specific reason?

Comment: Because slots work a little differently and require a direct parent.